# Suspended SIM in Bangladesh

Tags: cellphones, bangladesh

I'm in Bangladesh now, and a week ago I bought a Grameenphone SIM card (voice + data). I recharged it yesterday and now I can't use it (it says "service suspended"). I am sure I have enough credit; I registered using my passport so that shouldn't be a problem. Do you have any guess on what happened, and tips on what should I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Gremeenphone Tech Support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have internet access then visit Grameenphone's (GP) [website](https://www.grameenphone.com/).There is a Live Chat option to talk with their representative.Use your GP number and Name before starting the chat. Or you can email them at *Insta.service@grameenphone.com*
describing your problems along with your phone number and passport number.

You can also visit the nearest Grameenphone center with your SIM. They can reconnect your number.